# Knockout.js $parents key name in template and removing observables

Tags: knockout.js, unbind, observable, parents

i have 2 simple questions regarding knockout:

1. How can I get $parents keys, eg. if my view model is:

   ```
   viewModel = { ModelA: { ModelB : { ModelC : { someprop } } } }
   ```

   and I have 3 templates, first template is rendering ModelA, second ModelB and third ModelC, how can I get the following in ModelC template:

   ```
   <a data-bind="visible: viewModel.{$parents[1].key}.{$parents[0].key}.{$data.key}.someprop" />
   ```
2. How can I remove observable someprop from ModelC in runtime. I tried to embed this in ModelC template:

   ```
   <input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: function() { viewModel.removeIt(someprop) }" />
   ```

   and this in root page

   ```
   viewModel.removeIt = function(node) {
       ko.cleanNode(node);
   };
   ```

   but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're attempting to do in your first question, but i've created a fiddle that should help answer it: http://jsfiddle.net/FwJWG/

As for removing an observable, you can just remove it from the class altogether using `delete`: http://jsfiddle.net/7sS8k/

Comment: Thanks for the delete option. Regarding 1st question, i wanted to get parent property name without hardcoding it in template (something like reflection in dotnet).